# @angular/service-worker/src/module.d.ts (30,9): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic

Tags: angular, push-notification, angular-service-worker

[image: this errro occure from serveiceWorker node_module]I have implemented "angular-push-notifications" in `angular-4` using this link:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/

I have done set-up "Service Workers" in the following way

```
1. add this package npm i -S @angular/pwa
2. enable service-worker in .angular-cli.json
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      },
      "serviceWorker": true
    }
```

and then start my server using `npm start`, and the server will throw me this error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/src/module.d.ts (30,9): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

I don't understand what I need to do in this case.

please help me to short out this error.

thank you in advance

Comment: That error means you are using a <AnyType> for ModuleWithProviders, but ModuleWithProviders is not expecting <AnyType>.

Comment: I don't think this is a typescript error

Comment: Well the generic type was added in September 2018 (https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/cbbad1b791d541093c9ffd68858fbb90d2c1af2d#diff-d3f0f5f34efd2b679fc85854b84a281a) which is surely after Angular 4. You like have a version conflict. Update your core or use an older version of the service worker.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, 
thank you for your response,
I have to only one option -> "use an older version of the service worker",
you have any idea to how to implement an older version of the service worker  with `SwPush`

Comment: It seems the push was added in Sep'17. https://github.com/angular/angular/commits/master/packages/service-worker/src/push.ts. Just add a version which was released later, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/service-worker (tab versions). You then have to install the chosen version. For example: 5.0.0

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, I have use service worker version "5.0.0-rc.0" and implement `SwPush` but it will throw me an error > `Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for SwPush! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for SwPush!`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191059/discussion-between-maulik-kanani-and-moxximanagarm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the `Service Workers` module and remove package `angular-push-notifications` in `angular-4`

and use custom push notification using socket.io with my database, 
I have set the logic when new record added in the DB, I have notified the user using custom notification